# Combine XY Coordinates with JPEG to make GEOTIFF

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff, jpeg-2000

I have a collection of 750 high-res jpeg images that are not geo-referenced, but for each of these images I have the center point coordinate as a shapefile. How can I merge these two so that I make a geotiff that uses each of those center XY coordinates to make a geotiff that I can than load into QGIS/ArcGIS?

Comment: One point isn't enough info. I assume you've got these images from a drone or aircraft mounted camera, is this the case? Can you explain where these images came from and how you calculated their centre coordinate?

Comment: @MichaelStimson, Hello, yes they came from an aircraft as part of a NASA GLiHT Mission. The coordinates were provided to me by folks at NASA and represent the center location of each photo. Each image has a unique ID that I can match with its center coordinate.

Comment: You need to orthorectify https://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki/orthorectification the images using a DEM, SRTM should do. You need to know where the sensor was and what tilt affects the images at the time the frame was taken.

Comment: @MichaelStimson thanks for your response. I'm going to make an inquiry to see if they have already performed any corrections. I think they might have.